# Setting titleLabel for UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel

I was a little confused to find today that the following does not work when trying to change the text shown on a `UIButton`.

```
// 001
[[[self button] titleLabel] setText:@"Peanuts"];
```

I think I know why, but I just wanted to confirm my thinking here. 001 does set the titleLabel text property, but as its a `UILabel` (a subview of the `UIButton`) it does not cause the UI to be redrawn. This results in an internal change to the `UILabel` text property, but sadly no visual change in the UI.

```
// 002
[[self button]setTitle:@"Peanuts" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It would seem that the method setTitle:forState is the correct way to go, it has the extra overhead of requiring a state but does invoke a UI redraw because its being called directly on the `UIButton`. My question is, is 002 the correct way to do this, it would seem it is unless I am doing something totally wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct.

```
[[self button]setTitle:@"Peanuts" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

is the way button titles should be set. This allows you to control what your button looks like in all of its different control states.

From the docs:

> In general, if a property is not specified for a state, the default is
>   to use the UIControlStateNormal value. If the value for
>   UIControlStateNormal is not set, then the property defaults to a
>   system value. Therefore, at a minimum, you should set the value for
>   the normal state.